# fixed position element judder in chrome on android when scrolled

Tags: android, mobile, position, fixed

I have a div containing an anchor that ive rotated and position: fixed in the upper left hand corner of the screen. it jumps around all crazy in my atrix hd when any scrolling is going on. -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch in the divs css does nothing. here's my meta viewport thing if that might matter 
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=100%, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>`
html for the div in question
`<div id="shop" class="center">
        <a href="#" class="railway">
            SHOP
        </a>
     </div>`
the css
     `#shop {
    position: fixed;
    left: -72px;
    top: 14px;
    background-color: #F03C2E;
    -ie-transform: rotate(314deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(314deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(314deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(314deg);
     transform: rotate(314deg);
     width: 192px;
     z-index: 10;
     test-align: center;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where your #shop element is placed, but maybe you did the same as me.

If a container has `position: fixed;` and its parent has it too, then this jumping behaviour while scrolling appear on my google nexus in chrome as well.

Solution:
It doesn't make sense to have a fixed container in a fixed container, remove the fixed position property from one of them.